# PHP CLI not picking up changes to freetds.conf for ODBC connection

Tags: sql-server, odbc, php, freetds

I had everything set up and working for years, this script that did price updates on a customers website via their local SAP database.

They just changed ISP's and thus, their IP address has changed. I've made all necessary changes to the outbound firewall and freetds.conf (odbc host config file) on our web server. However when I run the script from the command line (Its never run via apache, only via cron) it still attempts its connection to the OLD IP, which I have verified via the use of TCPDUMP.

Nothing I have tried gets PHP to see the new "host ip" in the freetds.conf file.

Is there any way to get this to work without rebooting the server? Is there some way to use the freebcp tool to force a reload of the config file?

There has to be a way to do this without rebooting. This is linux after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was just editing the wrong config file. Everything worked immediately once I updated the correct file. Reboots or restarts required.

Comment: Should the last line be 'No reboots or restarts required'?